# VBA - Utilizar valores de uma coluna para montar tabela

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Bom dia,

Eu estou extraindo uma base de dados com datas e número de ocorrências. Mas para meu modelo estatístico eu preciso organizar ela de uma forma que apenas apareçam as datas multiplicado pelo número de ocorrências.

[image: Abaixo a tabela como veio]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu entendo que tenho que fazer um loop para armazenar os valores para depois utilizá-los, consegui com esse código, mas não sei como utilizar esse valores para montar minha tabela, se alguém puder me ajudar, por favor:

```
Sub table_array()

Dim myTable As ListObject
Dim myArray As Variant

Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabela1")
myArray = myTable.DataBodyRange

'Loop through each item in the Table Array (displayed in Immediate Window [ctrl + g])


 For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    Debug.Print myArray(x, 2)
          
 Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui achar a resposta

Sub table_array()

Dim myTable As ListObject
Dim myArray As Variant

'Definir o nome da tabela no Excel e se necessário modificar abaixo
Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabela1")
myArray = myTable.DataBodyRange
Dim i As Date
Dim Linha As Integer

'Loop through each item in the Table Array (displayed in Immediate Window [ctrl + g])
' Linha mostra em qual linha serão incluídos os valores

Linha = 2

' Essa função abaixo pega os dados do corpo da tabela

For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)

' Busca todos os valores da coluna 2 e usa o número encontrado para repetir as entradas na coluna um.
For Z = 1 To myArray(x, 2)
Cells(Linha, 6).Value = myArray(x, 1)
Linha = Linha + 1

Next

Next

End Sub